# Algo raro hay en la versión disponible para actualizar miniconda3 mediante winget, en vez de aparecer una versión nueva, aparece una antigua

Tags: windows, anaconda

En la powershell ejecuto el comando:

```
winget upgrade
```

Y me aparece una supuesta nueva versión de miniconda3, pero que en realidad es más antigua, y claro cuando actualizo todos los paquetes de winget el problema es que en vez de actualizar
la versión más bien regresa a una anterior.
¿Cómo podría hacer para que cuando intente actualizar todos los paquetes de winget, ignore el de miniconda3?
[image: Captura de pantalla de la powershell]